# Unable to compile in fortran. Undefined symbols for arch i386/x86_64

Tags: architecture, fortran

I just started to use Fortran for a numerical project I am working on and have already run in to trouble. My problem is I want to use an (existing) module for computations of derivatives. When I compile this module and tries their test program I get either `"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:" or "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"` depending on which -arch I am compiling the module. I am not sure how I can solve this?

Sorry for the inconvinience.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"___ad_assign_MOD_assig_ff", referenced from:
      _a_full_ in ccD1DCJ9.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "___ad_assign_MOD_assig_ff", referenced from:
      _a_full_ in test.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

So you probably have a ccD1DCJ9.f90 source file and a test.f90 source file with an a_full routine in there, which calls a module routine. It looks, like the module file was produced and available while compiling, but you are missing the object code of that module file while linking. You'd have to show us your build setup in more detail to get more specific answers what to do, but in general you have to make sure to include all the object files from your modules during linking.